# What may cause the parallel Java program running time quite different between runs?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, optimization, parallel-processing

I know there are many factors those could affect a Java program's running time. I tried to eliminate some of them, including:

- The warm-up runs are considered and not counted.
- `System.gc()` is called between any two runs.

But I found the data still variates much. Here is a sample when 10 threads are used:

```
157th run
0 run time: 9106171
1 run time: 9084652
2 run time: 8990820
3 run time: 8989474
5 run time: 9062850
4 run time: 9302010
9 run time: 9454475
8 run time: 9506585
7 run time: 9494990
6 run time: 9491779
total time: 31 ms

158th run
2 run time: 14754858
5 run time: 14865035
0 run time: 15759180
1 run time: 15988056
3 run time: 16660592
8 run time: 16340240
9 run time: 16544479
6 run time: 17280122
7 run time: 17249778
4 run time: 18026322
total time: 19 ms
```

I found for most runs, they took like 17~20 ms, but for <5% runs, they took like 25~31 ms. More interesting, in the later cases, each thread's running time is even **shorter**!

The main thread in this program only `start()` and `join()` the threads, and has no more work to do.

Could anyone provide some thoughts/hints ?

Comment: What are these threads actually doing?

Comment: 1st guess: JIT  warmup.  2nd guess: GC (as objects accumulate, and get swept away).  You've covered those.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) profile the app, 2) observe heap behavior at runtime

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Basically, each thread process a string segment and generate a tree data structure.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks. I don't have any profiler experience, do you have any recommendation?

Comment: Are you destroying / creating these threads for each run? If so it's non-deterministic as to how they will be scheduled, for instance in your 157th run they could all be on the same cpu core, whereas in the 158th they could be divided among 4 cores etc.

Comment: @DanielKinsman I used `taskset -c ***` to bind the 10 threads to 10 cores on the same chip.

Comment: @JackWM Reading up on taskset I think it only limits the process affinity to a given set of cpu cores, but it can't decide the *thread* affinity for you. I'll ask again, are you using a pool of threads that carries over from run to run, or creating and destroying threads every time?

Comment: @DanielKinsman Yes, it only provides process level affinity. I created and destroyed threads every run. They could run on different cores between runs. If you are considering cache locality, then how to explain the `31 ms` (is larger than `19 ms`)?

Answer (score 3):

I note you are starting and stopping threads. As the test is very short those thread only have time to be assigned to one (or a small number) of arrangement of cpus.  This arrangement could mean more threads are running at once but using hyperthreading, both cpus of a core are used.  When this happens, each thread is slowed down (as it has to share a core, cache etc) but the throughput is increased with reduced thread context switches and more efficient use of the core.  In another arrangement each core might have only one cpu busy, meaning each thread is faster, but the total run time is longer.

I would try using an ExecutorService, use the same number tasks as you have cpus (or some multiple) and re-use the threads. This will give you more consistency between runs and the OS will have time to place your threads in a more efficient manner.

I have written a library which will allow you to assign threads to different cpu layouts. e.g. sharing or not sharing cores. https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity

Comment: Yup - trying to bind the threads to cores to improve performance, but then using start/join:((

Comment: Affinity helps when you have a small number of critical threads which exist for the long periods of time. It can help reduce the unpredictability in tests as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say for the 157th run all threads ran on the one core. The bottleneck would simply be them waiting for each other in a queue like fashion. Each individual run was quick because they had sole reign over the memory resources, but in aggregate it was slow, because they all lined up and waited for their turn.

Let's say the 158th run was spread out across multiple cores. All would compete at once for memory / cache resources, so each thread took longer individually. But because they were all working at the same time, the process in general was finished quicker.

To test this hypothesis, reuse a pool of threads between runs, and manually set their affinity one way or the other.

That is just one possible explanation, there are likely other factors, it is all very non-deterministic. For example your operating system might have scheduled some other program at the same time (e.g. cron job).

Comment: What do you mean "but in aggregate it was slow"? the main thread did nothing except creating/destroying threads.

Comment: Processor affinity/OS scheduling might well be related - good suggestion, Daniel Kinsman!  Regarding "profiling", there are many resources.  JConsole is a great place to start.  See also this link:  http://www.infoq.com/articles/java-profiling-with-open-source

Comment: @JackWM The main thread sat there and waited for all the others to finish. That's what `join` does.

Comment: Do you mean the `join` has different times for different core-mappings? And this cause the large running time difference?

Comment: Also I don't understand "because they were all working at the same time, the process in general was finished quicker". Actually, I don't see the difference in the "join" part.

Comment: @JackWM The `join` just waits. What I am saying is that it took longer for all of the other threads doing the work took to finish. Look imagine a supermarket with only one checkout (cpu core) and a long line of customers (threads). It takes a long time to serve them all ("in aggregate") because they each have to wait. Now instead imagine 4 checkouts (cpu cores). It takes less total time to serve the same number of customers (threads).

Comment: But in my cases, there are always 10 cores available in total. How could the "one checkout" case occur? The scheduler never plan to assign all the 10 threads to 1 core when other 9 cores are available, that does not make any sense.

Comment: @JackWM because you aren't saying to the program "run each of these threads on a separate cpu core". You are saying "run each of these threads however you see fit". From run to run, it may choose differently.